# Assembly error handling

Tags: assembly, flags

I created a *function* for reading in *decimal numbers* in assembly, and I want to do something like **throwing an exception** if a **non-numeric character** is entered.
My idea was to set some **flag(s)** accordingly, and handle these in **main**.
Which **flags** are best for this situation, and how could I *set this/these*?

Comment: If you are talking about the flags register (carry flag, overflow flag, etc.), I would not use flags because they change everytime any instruction executes. I recommend you to use a variable to store some value to represent the exception error.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez "they change everytime any instruction executes" this is not true, many instructions do not affect the flags or only affect certain flags, and indeed several (ancient) system interfaces used flags to indicate error conditions, especially the carry flag (CF). In particular many x86 BIOS and DOS calls used the carry flag IIRC.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez "They change every tine any instruction executes" is a bit over the top...  Better to say that they could change unexpectedly when you return to your C code and it starts pawing at them. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the x86 architecture, the carry flag (CF) has been historically used for such purposes, probably because it is the most convenient to manipulate: the `STC` and `CLC` instructions can be used to set and clear it. The interrupt and direction flags (IF, DF) have similar instructions, but altering these flags tends has a significant impact on other code; the direction flag, in particular, is normally required by various calling conventions to be set one way or another, and the interrupt flag masks interrupts, a visible effect that should not depend on failure to parse an integer (for example).

While I wouldn't compare it to proper exception throwing and handling, setting the carry flag before return can indicate an error, and the caller can check the carry flag (using the `jc` instruction) on return to handle the error appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

so this is going to be abi dependent if you want to use an actual exception.... keep in mind there are no exceptions in C ABI, if you want to make a C++ exception that is *possible* but you wouldn't want to have to... if it is just for storing a status, just put it in a register, or copied to an address that is passed in if you need it to live higher up your call stack...

something that might work for you is to write a predefined address and call a signal, like SIGINT and have the signal handler fix things for you... this is a heavy handed way that something like exceptions could be done...